# йКак последовательно вывести функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.6

Нужна помощь в такой загадки как вывести две и более функции последовательно?Как можно заменить функцию без изменения кода когда функция повторяетца раз 20 в коде?

```
def r():
    q ='wrrewr'
    print(q)
def e():
    q = " iee"
    print(q)

def g():
    i = 3
    print(i)
    e() # надо чтоб е менялось на r при этом код выполнял последовательно.Как зделать?После выполнения е выполнялся r?
    u = 'jervmnofvndoivsb' 
    r = u.split()[-5]
    print(r)
    t = len(q)
    print(t)

while True:
    g()
    sleep(4600)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В питоне можно всё. Можно переменной, в которой лежит ссылка на функцию присвоить ссылку на другую функцию. Примерно так:

```
def func_a():
    print('func_a')

def func_b():
    print('func_b')

def func_test():
    func_a()

func_test()

def func_fun():
    print('func_fun')
    func_a_old()
    func_b()

func_a_old = func_a
func_a = func_fun

func_test()
```

Вывод при первом запуске `func_test()`, запустилась исходная функция `func_a`:

```
func_a
```

Вывод при втором запуске `func_test()`, вместо прописанной в ней функции `func_a` запустилась функция `func_fun`, которая запустила старую версию `func_a` и следом `func_b`:

```
func_fun
func_a
func_b
```

Тут важно заметить, что из функции с подменой `func_fun` нельзя запускать текущую `func_a`, потому что иначе в итоге `func_fun` будет вызывать сама себя рекурсивно.

Comment: Пасиб, понял но он не перезапишит ли переменную?Пасиб гляну.

Comment: Какую переменную? Если q, то её нужно объявлять глобальной в каждой функции где вы меняете её значение, иначе этих изменений никто не увидит

Comment: Все понял про глобальную и имел ввиду .Ок ,помог очень Пасиб.